# How to return multiple cell locations using Match and Address function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a column with thousands of records and I am trying to match a set of other inputs to it, while returning the location of the match from the range A:A.

The following formula does it fine (it returns a location of the presumably first record/match which is longer than two characters from column A), however I would like to get ALL locations of the match from the column A (in one cell if possible, but not necessary) where the searched word appears.

`=IFERROR(IF((LEN(H9)>2);(ADDRESS(MATCH("*"&H9&"*";$A$2:$A$100000;0);1));"");"")`

I have tried the Textjoin function, but it still returns only one location despite multiple occurrence of the searched word (maybe I'm doing it wrong?).

`=TEXTJOIN(";";TRUE;IF((LEN(I2)>2);(ADDRESS(MATCH("*"&I2&"*";A2:A100000;0);1));A2:A100000))`

To illustrate better what I'm trying to achieve: Let's say there is word "ball" in the cell H9 and I can see that cell A33; A10 and A222 have the word ball in its content (e.g. handball;football;basketball) - therefore the desired output would be A33;A10;A222 in the destination cell(s).

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA - Function Stops after using FindNext (Works in Subroutine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666720/excel-vba-function-stops-after-using-findnext-works-in-subroutine).  I voted to close as the answer given by @ChrisNeilsen on the link is very close to what you're after (given the `VBA` tag).

Comment: On the link above remove the `Debug` line add `ReturnAddress = ReturnAddress & foundItem.Address & ", "` straight after the `Do`, add `ReturnAddress = Left(ReturnAddress, Len(ReturnAddress) - 2)` straight after the `Loop While...` and change the return to `FindAllCells = ReturnAddress`.

Comment: Amazing, it does exactly what I need! thank you so much :)

Comment: Was writing up an answer when came across the `FindNext` problem - forgot it did that so looked for workaround and found your answer. :)  You may want to delete the question as it's not likely to get an answer now you've got it.