# FindNext in error when called from a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a UDF to get all matches in a column and return an array of indexes.

It works fine when called from a Sub.  But, when called from an Excel cell, it fails to find all matches and returns only the first.

Here is a picture of the data in worksheet. (sorry, I don't know how to insert a mini-worksheet.)
Basically, it has a column of 6 cells, containing "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", and "c".  There are also two formulas calling MatchAllInCol, one attempts to match "a", and the other "g".  The former should yield an array of {1, 4} and spill into the next cell to the right, but it doesn't.  Because FindNext in UDF failed to find the next match.  The latter dutifully shows "#VALUE!" as result.  No problem there.

The worksheet cells of data and formula
[image]

And here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Function MatchAllInCol(what As String, inCol As Range) As Variant
' finds all occurrences of 'what' in a column 'inCol'
' and returns an array of indexes of found items
' if no matches, return an array with UBound of -1
' 'inCol' must be a single column
On Error GoTo debug_:
MatchAllInCol = Split("") ' This Split call returns an array with UBound of -1
If inCol.Columns.Count <> 1 Then
    Exit Function
    End If
Dim found As Range, lastCell As Range
' start searching after the last cell
Set lastCell = inCol.Cells(inCol.Rows.Count, 1)
Set found = inCol.Find(what:=what _
    , LookIn:=xlValues _
    , LookAt:=xlWhole _
    , after:=lastCell _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
    , SearchDirection:=xlNext _
    , MatchCase:=False _
    , MatchByte:=True _
    )
If found Is Nothing Then Exit Function
Dim firstAddr As String
firstAddr = found.Address
Dim matches As String
matches = found.Row - inCol.Row + 1

Const delim As String = "＠" ' this character must not appear in inCol
Do
    ' PROBLEM: FindNext always finds nothing if UDF called from a cell
    Set found = inCol.FindNext(after:=found) 
    If found Is Nothing Then Exit Do
    If found.Address = firstAddr Then Exit Do
    matches = matches & delim & found.Row - inCol.Row + 1
Loop

If Len(matches) <> 0 Then MatchAllInCol = Split(matches, delim)
Exit Function
debug_:
    Debug.Print "ERROR:" & Err.Description & " from " & Err.Source
    Stop
End Function

Sub MatchAllInCol_TEST()
' this works if called from VBA
    Dim rng As Range, res As Variant
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B7")
    res = MatchAllInCol("b", rng)
    Dim ii As Long
    If UBound(res) = -1 Then MsgBox ("nothing found") _
    Else MsgBox ("found: " & Application.TextJoin(", ", False, res))
End Sub
```

I have attached a test Sub at the end, which shows that MatchAllInCol works as coded.
But, when called from a cell, the UDF fails to find the second match.

Very puzzling.  I have been struggling with it for several days now, and searched high and low, and could not find an answer.  Can anyone shed a light on this, please?

By the way, Microsoft document gives an example with FindNext method, which is wrong, as it enters into an endless loop.

```
Sub FindValue()
' Below is from Microsoft document.
' There is a problem in the example provided in Microsoft document
' This code give will loop forever.
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext
    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A500")
        Set c = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                c.Value = 5
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57667237/445425)

Comment: Yes, it did.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chris neilsen, the problem is solved by using another Find, abandoning the faulty FindNext.

Please see the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57667237/445425) provided by Chris.

As indicated in the reference, people should know that, FindNext does not work if your function is called from a cell.

The lesson is, you should always use Find in your UDF.  Avoid FindNext.